# Why are huge challot displayed on the wedding couple / Bar Mitzvah's table?

Tags: minhag, wedding, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, challah-shabbat-bread

I noticed that among Orthodox and, seemingly Hareidi Bar Mitzvah's and weddings, a huge challah is cut by the chattan or Bar Mitzvah.

I assume that there must be some *minhag* behind this that originated somewhere for some reason. I don't think it's just to feed the attendants, because usually bread or rolls is available in a table bread basket or at each seating, and the challah is usually cut (esp. at weddings) long after people ate the appetizer / first course.

Comment: I haven’t seen this at Bar Mitzvahs, and at weddings it’s usually meant for everyone at the head table to eat their fill. Lots of people with big appetites necessitates a big loaf.

Comment: It's typically recommended to make brachos on nice things.  Particularly for a public hamotzi at a special occasion, it make sense to make praise Hashem for an extra fancy challah.

Comment: It's a giant waste of food.

Comment: For the caterer to charge for more

Answer (score 7):

The earliest source for having a large Challah at a wedding is the *[Maasas Binyomin](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1954&pgnum=13)* (d. 1620)

There is a wide spread custom to distribute slices of the large *challa* to the friends of the Chosson and Kallah. Some say (*Nittei Gavriel* quotes *Darkei Chaim* p27, who heard this from R' Akiva Eiger) that this is based on the famous question posed at every marriage: '**מצא** או **מוציא**' - every marriage has the potential to be ׳**מצא** אשה מצא טוב׳, or conversely to be '**מוצא** אני את האשה'. Therefore immediately after they partake of it, we remove the ׳**המוצא**׳ from in front of them, as if to symbolize that only one option remains - that of מצא אשה מצא טוב. (A similar sentiment is brought in the Beis Emes [authored by the Lev Simcha of Ger], based on Eruvin 54)

Comment: Will try follow up with source, if I can find it again

Comment: I thought it was מצא or מוצא אני את האשה כו׳. Not מוציא at all, which would then make המוציא irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the custom originated from the *halacha* that the *chosson* is בוצע תחילה (See *Berachos* 47, *Magen Avraham OC"H* 167.29); he is the first to 'break the bread'. It is possible that in the times when they observed this halacha, everyone partook of the bread from the central loaf which the *chosson* cut.

Today, this *halacha* is virtually obsolete, because at our weddings the public begin the meal and partake of the bread before the *chosson* and *kallah* arrive, and everybody has their own roll.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll see if I can check the source in Brachot.